# PG::Undefinedtable: ERROR: when run rake db:migrate on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my rails app that I made following the Rails 4 in action tutorial.  I've succesfully pushed to heroku but when a run rake db:migrate i'm getting this error:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ fast-lowlands-66439... up, run.6711 (Free)
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (10.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Migrating to CreateStates (20161123222713)
   (2.5ms)  BEGIN
== 20161123222713 CreateStates: migrating =====================================
-- create_table(:states)
-- add_reference(:tickets, :state, {:index=>true, :foreign_key=>true})
   (1.4ms)  ALTER TABLE "tickets" ADD "state_id" integer
   (9.7ms)  CREATE  INDEX  "index_tickets_on_state_id" ON "tickets"  ("state_id")
   (4.6ms)  ALTER TABLE "tickets" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_fc553dc329"
FOREIGN KEY ("state_id")
  REFERENCES "states" ("id")

   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "states" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "tickets" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_fc553dc329"
FOREIGN KEY ("state_id")
  REFERENCES "states" ("id")
```

The app works locally and the tables do exist.
Let me know if you need any additional files post.
Thanks as always for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would drop the database on heroku and recreate it(You will loose all data saved to the db):

```
    heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL --confirm your_app_name
```

Replace your_app_name with the app name on heroku, but leave DATABASE_URL as it is.

Then run:

```
    heroku run rake db:setup
```

It will run both of these commands:

```
    heroku run rake db:migrate 
    heroku run rake db:seed
```

And you should be set.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that your previous migrations are missing. You can try to do this as steps below:

```
heroku run rake db:create
heroku run rake db:schema:load
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: [Heroku documentation](https://help.heroku.com/63D7ALXT/why-am-i-seeing-user-does-not-have-connect-privilege-error-with-heroku-postgres-on-review-apps) verifies use of `rake db:schema:load` I was having trouble with the accepted error until I tried this.